# Can ping server, but not browse

Tags: windows, networking, vmware, nextcloud

I'm trying to set up a personal cloud server on a Surface Pro, but I'm running into a networking issue that has me completely stumped.

My setup looks like this: I've installed a Nextcloud server on a VMWare virtual machine that's running Ubuntu 16.04, and I have it configured to use NAT so the virtual machine shares a fixed ip address with the host machine. I've forwarded ports 80, 443, etc. on the host machine's NAT device so requests go to the virtual machine. Additionally I've configured my router to have a static ip address, and I've forwarded all the relevant ports to the Surface Pro on my router.

So the trouble is that I can't connect to my server from my browser. HOWEVER, I am able to ping my server, I can SSH in to both the virtual machine and the host machine from the internet, and I am able to access the server in my browser from any computer that's connected to LAN, no problem.

This all sounds like it could be a firewall issue to me (maybe port 80 is blocked on the host machine for some reason??) but the fact that I have no trouble accessing the server from LAN is confusing the issue, and also deactivating the firewall on the host machine doesn't solve the issue.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem! It turns out the NAT device was improperly configured to use its own DHCP service rather than using the local DHCP service. Basically it was assigning a LAN IP address 169.254.72.176 to the virtual machine, while everything else was configured to expect that the virtual machine's IP address was fixed at 192.168.34.43.